# How to give the parameter to C#'s function from C++?

Tags: c#, c++-cli

Caller: C++ code
Callee: C# code

C# Code:

```
public int CSharpMethodName(string str, params object[] args)
{
   ....
}
```

C++ Code:

```
bool CPPMethodName(const CString& cstr, CString parameters[])
{
      //The object is already initialized with gcroot in order to access to C# code. 

     //Here I want to give parameters to the CSharpMethodName
     result = obj->CSharpMethodName(gcnew System::String(sqlQuery), parameters);
}
```

This is the signature for C# method when added to the C++ project as a reference:
`CSharpMethodName(System::String^, ... array<System::Object^>^)`

How can I give the CString array type of the parameters to the CSharp method? Please let me know if anything is not clear.

Thanks

Comment: CPPMethodName() is broken, it needs an extra parameter to pass the array size.  Now it is easy to convert the array.

Comment: `System::String^` – this is not valid in C++ – this is C++-CLI, which is a different language (a nearly superset of C++ just as C++ nearly is of C – in both cases there are minimal differences).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I have to convert unmanaged array to managed array.

Here is the complete code that works for me:

```
bool CPPMethodName(const CString& cstr, const CString parameters[], size_t size)
{
      cli::array<System::String^>^ managedParametersArray = GetManagedArray(parameters, size);
      result = obj->CSharpMethodName(gcnew System::String(sqlQuery), managedParametersArray );

      return result;
}

cli::array<System::String^>^ AdoHelperWrapper::GetManagedArray(const CString paramaters[], size_t size)
{
    cli::array<System::String^>^ result = gcnew cli::array<System::String^>(size);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        result[i] = gcnew System::String(paramaters[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```